hx-put and hx-post not followed on form submission
When submitting a html form with a hx-put or hx-post attribute a GET request is send instead of a POST or PUT request.
Given the following html document based on the HTMX example here: https://htmx.org/examples/click-to-edit/
<html>
    <body>
        <form hx-put="/contact/1" hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
  <div>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="Joe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="Blow">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="joe@blow.com">
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  <button class="btn" hx-get="/contact/1">Cancel</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

I expect that a PUT request is send to /contact/1 but when actually trying this in chrome (Version 127.0.6533.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) a GET requests is send instead with the fields as query parameters. I have also tried this with hx-post and also on firefox but in both cases a GET request is send.

Of course i'am an idiot and forgot you need to add the htmx js library. Adding <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.1"></script> to the script fixed my problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
